# ScriptRunConfig with datastore reference on AML

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When trying to run a ScriptRunConfig, using :

```py
src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=project_folder, 
                      script='train.py', 
                      arguments=['--input-data-dir', ds.as_mount(),
                                 '--reg', '0.99'],
                      run_config=run_config) 
run = experiment.submit(config=src)
```

It doesn't work and breaks with this when I submit the job :

```
... lots of things... and then
TypeError: Object of type 'DataReference' is not JSON serializable
```

However if I run it with the Estimator, it works. One of the differences is the fact that with a `ScriptRunConfig` we're using a list for parameters and the other is a dictionary.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being able to use `DataReference` in `ScriptRunConfig` is a bit more involved than doing just `ds.as_mount()`. You will need to convert it into a string in `arguments` and then update the `RunConfiguration`'s `data_references` section with the `DataReferenceConfiguration` created from `ds`. Please [see here](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/training/train-on-remote-vm/train-on-remote-vm.ipynb) for an example notebook on how to do that.

If you are just reading from the input location and not doing any writes to it, please check out [`Dataset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-create-register-datasets). It allows you to do exactly what you are doing without doing anything extra. [Here is an example notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets-tutorial/train-with-datasets.ipynb) that shows this in action.

Below is a short version of the notebook

```py
from azureml.core import Dataset

# more imports and code

ds = Datastore(workspace, 'mydatastore')
dataset = Dataset.File.from_files(path=(ds, 'path/to/input-data/within-datastore'))

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=project_folder, 
                      script='train.py', 
                      arguments=['--input-data-dir', dataset.as_named_input('input').as_mount(),
                                 '--reg', '0.99'],
                      run_config=run_config) 
run = experiment.submit(config=src)
```

Comment: Hi the link `Please see here for an example notebook on how to do that.` does not actually contain how to `convert it into a string and then update the RunConfiguration's data_references`. Could you please elaborate? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can see this link [how-to-migrate-from-estimators-to-scriptrunconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-migrate-from-estimators-to-scriptrunconfig) in official documents.

The core code of using **DataReference** in **ScriptRunConfig**  is

```
# if you want to pass a DataReference object, such as the below:
datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
data_ref = datastore.path('./foo').as_mount()

src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='.',
                      script='train.py',
                      arguments=['--data-folder', str(data_ref)], # cast the DataReference object to str
                      compute_target=compute_target,
                      environment=pytorch_env)
src.run_config.data_references = {data_ref.data_reference_name: data_ref.to_config()} # set a dict of the DataReference(s) you want to the `data_references` attribute of the ScriptRunConfig's underlying RunConfiguration object.
```